Not possible to write to Log file as a non-admin user when it was created as Admin
On the initial execution of my program, it generates a Logs directory and a log file file, then begins writing to the log file. Location: C:\ProgramData\MyCompanyName\MyProductName\Logs\RA.log
If the user runs my program as an administrator for the first time, the RA.log file is created with admin permissions. Consequently, when the program is later run as a regular user, it cannot write to the RA.log file, because the user itself doesn't even appear in the list of permissions of RA.log, and the group that the user belongs to has only RX permissions (Read and execute).
As a result, the log is not written anymore.
To solve it, I defined some NLOG configuration to create a fallback log, so is it's not possible to write to RA.log , an "archive" folder is created and current RA.log should be copied to it and a new RA.log should be created.
The problem is that the current user doesn't have permissions to copy the RA.log file.
What is the best way to solve it ?
